# Tooltip Hover State

Tags: hover, highcharts, tooltip

I've overridden the color of a bar in a bar chart by acting directly on the graphic. It works on initial load, but if I hover over the bar to display the tooltip, when I mouseout, it reverts to the default color, not my custom choice.

How would I edit the settings for that event on just the one bar.

See:
http://jsfiddle.net/WQkeQ/4/

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max:4000,
                title: {
                    text: 'Population (millions)',
                    align: 'high'
                },
                labels: {
                    overflow: 'justify'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    if(this.y > (this.series.chart.yAxis[0].max))
                        return this.series.name +': '+ this.y + ' max is smaller: '+this.series.chart.yAxis[0].max ;
                    else
                        return this.series.name +': '+ this.y;
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Year 2008',
                data: [973, 914, 4054, 732, 34]
            }]
        },function(chart){

            var max = chart.yAxis[0].max,
                content = '<h2>Points</h2><br/>';

            $.each(chart.series,function(i,serie){
                $.each(serie.data,function(j,data){
                    if(data.y > max){
                       content += 'Point: '+data.y+' is bigger than max: '+max;
                       data.graphic.attr({fill:'silver'});}
                });
            });

            $('#report').html(content);

        });
    });

});
```

Hover over silver bar.

Thanks,
Manisha

Comment: I do see that editing the opacity, instead of the color works around my display issue. It makes the bar appear a different color, but it isn't really. So the hover/mouse over/out event doesn't appear to change the color. It's not understanding the question originally posed but an effective work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manisha, You can use [**`CSS`**](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Element.css%28%29) property for **elements** to set the color for the single bar in the series.

#### use

```
    data.graphic.css({color: 'silver' });
```

#### instead of

```
    data.graphic.attr({fill:'silver'});
```

[**`Fiddled`**](http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/WQkeQ/5/) Version.

Hope this helps.